# does response.redirect('route') makes all the middlewares for that route run again in express

Tags: node.js, express

does `response.redirect('route')` makes all the middlewares for that route run again ?

Is `response.redirect('route')`

like client making a new request to the server ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.
In fact, when the redirection occurs, after the `302 found` response, the client will make the request on the redirected url anyway.

Example:

```
app.use('/some/route', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('some middleware')
  next()
})

app.get('/some/route', (req, res) => {
  res.end()
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/some/route')
})
```

Test:

```
$ curl -L yourdomain.com/    // -> some middleware
```